# Uploading Files in Django - How to avoid the increase of files in the upload directory

Tags: django, python-3.x, file-upload

I've been working on uploading a file on Django. I have the following code to run things.

```
def handle_uploaded_file(file, filename):
    if not os.path.exists('upload/'):
        os.mkdir('upload/')

    with open('upload/' + filename, 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in file.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)

def upload_csv(request):
    # Get the context from the request.
    context = RequestContext(request)

    if request.is_ajax():
        if "POST" == request.method:
            csv_file = request.FILES['file']
            my_df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, header=0)
            handle_uploaded_file(csv_file, str(csv_file))
            .............................
            .............................
```

As you can see above, I have been uploading files to the upload directory. However, my concern is that this type of method might not be that much efficient because each file is kept and stored in that folder. What if hundreds or thousands of files are uploaded each week? See this:

[image]

What would be the other way to efficiently and effectively upload files?

Comment: The only real concern is your hardware; disk (or network) speed may affect performance, and you need enough storage space. A webserver like Apache or IIS should be serving your static and uploaded content. They can handle it efficiently. If you really needed to offload that work, you could use AWS S3 storage, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is considered best practice to store your uploaded files on a disk.
There is no way around. You must provide enough disk space on your server. In addition, you could automatically block uploads if you are running out of disk space.

> Storing files in a database should never happen. If it’s being
>   considered as a solution for a problem, find a certified  database
>   expert and ask for a second opinion.

Source: [Two Scopes of Django](https://www.twoscoopspress.com/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-8).

---

If you concerned about the [file limit within a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944709/windows-limit-on-no-of-files-in-a-particular-folder) you could introduce subfolders to your `upload` directory. For example `upload/category/year/filename`. You can take advantage of the [`FileField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField).

```
def document_directory_path(instance, filename):
    path = 'upload/{}/%Y/{}'.format(instance.category.slug, filename)
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(path)


class Document(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=document_directory_path)

    def filename(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.file.name)
```

Another similar example that groups your uploads by the user (uploader) id can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to).

---

Last but not least, you have the option to move to a cloud provider. Which can be pricey if you expect thousands of files and a lot of traffic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Yannic. Don't you think it it better to write a service program (windows service for windows server or cron job for linux) to delete the files under that folder? For example, that kind of small service program can delete all yesterday files every day.

Comment: If you don't have an async task queue like ``celery`` within your project I would go with a ``cron`` job. The equivalent to it would be a windows scheduled task (not a windows service).

Comment: Yeah, I applied [this](https://pureinfotech.com/delete-files-older-than-days-windows-10/) and it worked. Thanks again Yannic.