# Best Way To Serve Images in Django 3.0?

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-3.0

So I 'm working on a project in django - it's like a variation of a blog. There will be 4 mini blogs within the website and the admin for each can create new posts - so they can also add an image to their post.

Now that django has recently been update (django 3.0 is here), I was wondering, what is the best way to store and serve these images in production? Could someone maybe link to a part in the documentation? I don't think this will come under staticfiles will it? I searched the documentation with keywords like "Media", "Serving images" etc but didn't really find much.

EDIT: The project is quite small and I want to save files inside a folder of my django project.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/files/ How you store and serve user uploaded files will depend a lot on how and where your app is deployed

Comment: Storing files in a database should never happen. If it’s being considered as a solution for a problem, find a certified database expert and ask for a second opinion. - Two Scopes of Django Book.
This may give you more idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48958888/uploading-files-in-django-how-to-avoid-the-increase-of-files-in-the-upload-dir